# Driver taints kernel and can't be unloaded

Tags: c, linux, linux-kernel, linux-device-driver, kernel-module

I have built a kernel module which is causing some problem. Some time after loading it, the driver stops working and at that moment, when I try to use `rmmod` to unload it, it blocks and I have to manually restart my device. I have managed to get this trace by using the main console of my card with a USB-TTL connexion:

```
Probe: Successful
xeno_sprinte_ida on AUART3: physical address=0x80070000 membase=0xc8e3c000 irq=234 uartclk=24000000
Init: Successful
------------[ cut here ]------------
------------[ cut here ]------------
WARNING: CPU: 0 PID: 825 at drivers/clk/clk.c:130 clk_enable_lock+0x98/0xd4
Modules linked in: moduleXenoUartSimple(O-) snd_soc_mxs_sgtl5000 snd_soc_sgtl5000 snd_soc_mxs snd_soc_mxs_pcm snd_soc_core snd_pcm_dmaengine snd_pcm snd_timer snd soundcore ums_alauda uas ums_onetouch ums_cypress ums_karma ums_jumpshot ums_eneub6250 firmware_class ums_usbat ums_sddr55 ums_sddr09 ums_freecom ums_datafab ums_isd200 ums_realtek usb_storage scsi_mod ci_hdrc_usb2 ci_hdrc_imx usbmisc_imx ci_hdrc ehci_hcd usbmon usbcore usb_common mxs_mmc sdhci_pltfm sdhci mmc_block mmc_core jffs2 ntfs ext2 vfat fat ipv6 lm75 hwmon fuse xeno_udd xeno_rtipc xeno_can_flexcan xeno_can [last unloaded: moduleXenoUartSimple]
CPU: 0 PID: 825 Comm: rmmod Tainted: G           O    4.9.24-ipipe-SPOS-0.2 #1
Hardware name: Freescale MXS (Device Tree)
I-pipe domain: Linux
[<c000f540>] (unwind_backtrace) from [<c000d5d0>] (show_stack+0x10/0x14)
[<c000d5d0>] (show_stack) from [<c0018cb0>] (__warn+0xd4/0xfc)
[<c0018cb0>] (__warn) from [<c0018d88>] (warn_slowpath_null+0x20/0x28)
[<c0018d88>] (warn_slowpath_null) from [<c0250dfc>] (clk_enable_lock+0x98/0xd4)
[<c0250dfc>] (clk_enable_lock) from [<c0252500>] (clk_core_enable_lock+0xc/0x2c)
[<c0252500>] (clk_core_enable_lock) from [<c0282ac0>] (pl011_console_write+0x20/0x1ac)
[<c0282ac0>] (pl011_console_write) from [<c00480f0>] (call_console_drivers.constprop.11+0x98/0xac)
[<c00480f0>] (call_console_drivers.constprop.11) from [<c0049104>] (console_unlock+0x2d0/0x6f0)
[<c0049104>] (console_unlock) from [<c00497e4>] (vprintk_emit+0x2c0/0x49c)
[<c00497e4>] (vprintk_emit) from [<c0049b4c>] (vprintk_default+0x20/0x28)
[<c0049b4c>] (vprintk_default) from [<c00ade9c>] (printk+0xe8/0x188)
[<c00ade9c>] (printk) from [<c0018c04>] (__warn+0x28/0xfc)
[<c0018c04>] (__warn) from [<c0018d88>] (warn_slowpath_null+0x20/0x28)
[<c0018d88>] (warn_slowpath_null) from [<c0252464>] (clk_core_disable_lock+0x18/0x24)
[<c0252464>] (clk_core_disable_lock) from [<bf2fc184>] (rt_mxs_auart_remove+0x1c/0x54 [moduleXenoUartSimple])
[<bf2fc184>] (rt_mxs_auart_remove [moduleXenoUartSimple]) from [<c028f620>] (__device_release_driver+0x70/0xfc)
[<c028f620>] (__device_release_driver) from [<c028feb8>] (driver_detach+0xfc/0x100)
[<c028feb8>] (driver_detach) from [<c028f1f4>] (bus_remove_driver+0x4c/0xa0)
[<c028f1f4>] (bus_remove_driver) from [<bf2fcdd8>] (rt_mxs_auart_exit+0xc/0x20 [moduleXenoUartSimple])
[<bf2fcdd8>] (rt_mxs_auart_exit [moduleXenoUartSimple]) from [<c006fd5c>] (SyS_delete_module+0x15c/0x1cc)
[<c006fd5c>] (SyS_delete_module) from [<c000a500>] (ret_fast_syscall+0x0/0x38)
---[ end trace 94d65edb72d57359 ]---
------------[ cut here ]------------
WARNING: CPU: 0 PID: 825 at drivers/clk/clk.c:131 clk_enable_lock+0xc0/0xd4
Modules linked in: moduleXenoUartSimple(O-) snd_soc_mxs_sgtl5000 snd_soc_sgtl5000 snd_soc_mxs snd_soc_mxs_pcm snd_soc_core snd_pcm_dmaengine snd_pcm snd_timer snd soundcore ums_alauda uas ums_onetouch ums_cypress ums_karma ums_jumpshot ums_eneub6250 firmware_class ums_usbat ums_sddr55 ums_sddr09 ums_freecom ums_datafab ums_isd200 ums_realtek usb_storage scsi_mod ci_hdrc_usb2 ci_hdrc_imx usbmisc_imx ci_hdrc ehci_hcd usbmon usbcore usb_common mxs_mmc sdhci_pltfm sdhci mmc_block mmc_core jffs2 ntfs ext2 vfat fat ipv6 lm75 hwmon fuse xeno_udd xeno_rtipc xeno_can_flexcan xeno_can [last unloaded: moduleXenoUartSimple]
CPU: 0 PID: 825 Comm: rmmod Tainted: G        W  O    4.9.24-ipipe-SPOS-0.2 #1
Hardware name: Freescale MXS (Device Tree)
I-pipe domain: Linux
[<c000f540>] (unwind_backtrace) from [<c000d5d0>] (show_stack+0x10/0x14)
[<c000d5d0>] (show_stack) from [<c0018cb0>] (__warn+0xd4/0xfc)
[<c0018cb0>] (__warn) from [<c0018d88>] (warn_slowpath_null+0x20/0x28)
[<c0018d88>] (warn_slowpath_null) from [<c0250e24>] (clk_enable_lock+0xc0/0xd4)
[<c0250e24>] (clk_enable_lock) from [<c0252500>] (clk_core_enable_lock+0xc/0x2c)
[<c0252500>] (clk_core_enable_lock) from [<c0282ac0>] (pl011_console_write+0x20/0x1ac)
[<c0282ac0>] (pl011_console_write) from [<c00480f0>] (call_console_drivers.constprop.11+0x98/0xac)
[<c00480f0>] (call_console_drivers.constprop.11) from [<c0049104>] (console_unlock+0x2d0/0x6f0)
[<c0049104>] (console_unlock) from [<c00497e4>] (vprintk_emit+0x2c0/0x49c)
[<c00497e4>] (vprintk_emit) from [<c0049b4c>] (vprintk_default+0x20/0x28)
[<c0049b4c>] (vprintk_default) from [<c00ade9c>] (printk+0xe8/0x188)
[<c00ade9c>] (printk) from [<c0018c04>] (__warn+0x28/0xfc)
[<c0018c04>] (__warn) from [<c0018d88>] (warn_slowpath_null+0x20/0x28)
[<c0018d88>] (warn_slowpath_null) from [<c0252464>] (clk_core_disable_lock+0x18/0x24)
[<c0252464>] (clk_core_disable_lock) from [<bf2fc184>] (rt_mxs_auart_remove+0x1c/0x54 [moduleXenoUartSimple])
[<bf2fc184>] (rt_mxs_auart_remove [moduleXenoUartSimple]) from [<c028f620>] (__device_release_driver+0x70/0xfc)
[<c028f620>] (__device_release_driver) from [<c028feb8>] (driver_detach+0xfc/0x100)
[<c028feb8>] (driver_detach) from [<c028f1f4>] (bus_remove_driver+0x4c/0xa0)
[<c028f1f4>] (bus_remove_driver) from [<bf2fcdd8>] (rt_mxs_auart_exit+0xc/0x20 [moduleXenoUartSimple])
[<bf2fcdd8>] (rt_mxs_auart_exit [moduleXenoUartSimple]) from [<c006fd5c>] (SyS_delete_module+0x15c/0x1cc)
[<c006fd5c>] (SyS_delete_module) from [<c000a500>] (ret_fast_syscall+0x0/0x38)
---[ end trace 94d65edb72d5735a ]---
WARNING: CPU: 0 PID: 825 at drivers/clk/clk.c:594 clk_core_disable_lock+0x18/0x24
Modules linked in: moduleXenoUartSimple(O-) snd_soc_mxs_sgtl5000 snd_soc_sgtl5000 snd_soc_mxs snd_soc_mxs_pcm snd_soc_core snd_pcm_dmaengine snd_pcm snd_timer snd soundcore ums_alauda uas ums_onetouch ums_cypress ums_karma ums_jumpshot ums_eneub6250 firmware_class ums_usbat ums_sddr55 ums_sddr09 ums_freecom ums_datafab ums_isd200 ums_realtek usb_storage scsi_mod ci_hdrc_usb2 ci_hdrc_imx usbmisc_imx ci_hdrc ehci_hcd usbmon usbcore usb_common mxs_mmc sdhci_pltfm sdhci mmc_block mmc_core jffs2 ntfs ext2 vfat fat ipv6 lm75 hwmon fuse xeno_udd xeno_rtipc xeno_can_flexcan xeno_can [last unloaded: moduleXenoUartSimple]
CPU: 0 PID: 825 Comm: rmmod Tainted: G        W  O    4.9.24-ipipe-SPOS-0.2 #1
Hardware name: Freescale MXS (Device Tree)
I-pipe domain: Linux
[<c000f540>] (unwind_backtrace) from [<c000d5d0>] (show_stack+0x10/0x14)
[<c000d5d0>] (show_stack) from [<c0018cb0>] (__warn+0xd4/0xfc)
[<c0018cb0>] (__warn) from [<c0018d88>] (warn_slowpath_null+0x20/0x28)
[<c0018d88>] (warn_slowpath_null) from [<c0252464>] (clk_core_disable_lock+0x18/0x24)
[<c0252464>] (clk_core_disable_lock) from [<bf2fc184>] (rt_mxs_auart_remove+0x1c/0x54 [moduleXenoUartSimple])
[<bf2fc184>] (rt_mxs_auart_remove [moduleXenoUartSimple]) from [<c028f620>] (__device_release_driver+0x70/0xfc)
[<c028f620>] (__device_release_driver) from [<c028feb8>] (driver_detach+0xfc/0x100)
[<c028feb8>] (driver_detach) from [<c028f1f4>] (bus_remove_driver+0x4c/0xa0)
[<c028f1f4>] (bus_remove_driver) from [<bf2fcdd8>] (rt_mxs_auart_exit+0xc/0x20 [moduleXenoUartSimple])
[<bf2fcdd8>] (rt_mxs_auart_exit [moduleXenoUartSimple]) from [<c006fd5c>] (SyS_delete_module+0x15c/0x1cc)
[<c006fd5c>] (SyS_delete_module) from [<c000a500>] (ret_fast_syscall+0x0/0x38)
---[ end trace 94d65edb72d5735b ]---
------------[ cut here ]------------
WARNING: CPU: 0 PID: 825 at drivers/clk/clk.c:140 clk_enable_unlock+0xb0/0xf8
Modules linked in: moduleXenoUartSimple(O-) snd_soc_mxs_sgtl5000 snd_soc_sgtl5000 snd_soc_mxs snd_soc_mxs_pcm snd_soc_core snd_pcm_dmaengine snd_pcm snd_timer snd soundcore ums_alauda uas ums_onetouch ums_cypress ums_karma ums_jumpshot ums_eneub6250 firmware_class ums_usbat ums_sddr55 ums_sddr09 ums_freecom ums_datafab ums_isd200 ums_realtek usb_storage scsi_mod ci_hdrc_usb2 ci_hdrc_imx usbmisc_imx ci_hdrc ehci_hcd usbmon usbcore usb_common mxs_mmc sdhci_pltfm sdhci mmc_block mmc_core jffs2 ntfs ext2 vfat fat ipv6 lm75 hwmon fuse xeno_udd xeno_rtipc xeno_can_flexcan xeno_can [last unloaded: moduleXenoUartSimple]
CPU: 0 PID: 825 Comm: rmmod Tainted: G        W  O    4.9.24-ipipe-SPOS-0.2 #1
Hardware name: Freescale MXS (Device Tree)
I-pipe domain: Linux
[<c000f540>] (unwind_backtrace) from [<c000d5d0>] (show_stack+0x10/0x14)
[<c000d5d0>] (show_stack) from [<c0018cb0>] (__warn+0xd4/0xfc)
[<c0018cb0>] (__warn) from [<c0018d88>] (warn_slowpath_null+0x20/0x28)
[<c0018d88>] (warn_slowpath_null) from [<c0252404>] (clk_enable_unlock+0xb0/0xf8)
[<c0252404>] (clk_enable_unlock) from [<bf2fc184>] (rt_mxs_auart_remove+0x1c/0x54 [moduleXenoUartSimple])
[<bf2fc184>] (rt_mxs_auart_remove [moduleXenoUartSimple]) from [<c028f620>] (__device_release_driver+0x70/0xfc)
[<c028f620>] (__device_release_driver) from [<c028feb8>] (driver_detach+0xfc/0x100)
[<c028feb8>] (driver_detach) from [<c028f1f4>] (bus_remove_driver+0x4c/0xa0)
[<c028f1f4>] (bus_remove_driver) from [<bf2fcdd8>] (rt_mxs_auart_exit+0xc/0x20 [moduleXenoUartSimple])
[<bf2fcdd8>] (rt_mxs_auart_exit [moduleXenoUartSimple]) from [<c006fd5c>] (SyS_delete_module+0x15c/0x1cc)
[<c006fd5c>] (SyS_delete_module) from [<c000a500>] (ret_fast_syscall+0x0/0x38)
---[ end trace 94d65edb72d5735c ]---
------------[ cut here ]------------
WARNING: CPU: 0 PID: 825 at drivers/clk/clk.c:141 clk_enable_unlock+0xe4/0xf8
Modules linked in: moduleXenoUartSimple(O-) snd_soc_mxs_sgtl5000 snd_soc_sgtl5000 snd_soc_mxs snd_soc_mxs_pcm snd_soc_core snd_pcm_dmaengine snd_pcm snd_timer snd soundcore ums_alauda uas ums_onetouch ums_cypress ums_karma ums_jumpshot ums_eneub6250 firmware_class ums_usbat ums_sddr55 ums_sddr09 ums_freecom ums_datafab ums_isd200 ums_realtek usb_storage scsi_mod ci_hdrc_usb2 ci_hdrc_imx usbmisc_imx ci_hdrc ehci_hcd usbmon usbcore usb_common mxs_mmc sdhci_pltfm sdhci mmc_block mmc_core jffs2 ntfs ext2 vfat fat ipv6 lm75 hwmon fuse xeno_udd xeno_rtipc xeno_can_flexcan xeno_can [last unloaded: moduleXenoUartSimple]
CPU: 0 PID: 825 Comm: rmmod Tainted: G        W  O    4.9.24-ipipe-SPOS-0.2 #1
Hardware name: Freescale MXS (Device Tree)
I-pipe domain: Linux
[<c000f540>] (unwind_backtrace) from [<c000d5d0>] (show_stack+0x10/0x14)
[<c000d5d0>] (show_stack) from [<c0018cb0>] (__warn+0xd4/0xfc)
[<c0018cb0>] (__warn) from [<c0018d88>] (warn_slowpath_null+0x20/0x28)
[<c0018d88>] (warn_slowpath_null) from [<c0252438>] (clk_enable_unlock+0xe4/0xf8)
[<c0252438>] (clk_enable_unlock) from [<bf2fc184>] (rt_mxs_auart_remove+0x1c/0x54 [moduleXenoUartSimple])
[<bf2fc184>] (rt_mxs_auart_remove [moduleXenoUartSimple]) from [<c028f620>] (__device_release_driver+0x70/0xfc)
[<c028f620>] (__device_release_driver) from [<c028feb8>] (driver_detach+0xfc/0x100)
[<c028feb8>] (driver_detach) from [<c028f1f4>] (bus_remove_driver+0x4c/0xa0)
[<c028f1f4>] (bus_remove_driver) from [<bf2fcdd8>] (rt_mxs_auart_exit+0xc/0x20 [moduleXenoUartSimple])
[<bf2fcdd8>] (rt_mxs_auart_exit [moduleXenoUartSimple]) from [<c006fd5c>] (SyS_delete_module+0x15c/0x1cc)
[<c006fd5c>] (SyS_delete_module) from [<c000a500>] (ret_fast_syscall+0x0/0x38)
---[ end trace 94d65edb72d5735d ]---
```

This doesn't always happen and sometimes I can `rmmod` it without any problem. I suspect that this is related to the clock because of the message `WARNING: CPU: 0 PID: 825 at drivers/clk/clk.c:130 clk_enable_lock`

If useful, here is part of the driver code that I'm using (inspired by `mxs-auart.c` and `rt_imx_uart.c`)

```
MODULE_LICENSE("GPL");
MODULE_DESCRIPTION("IMX28 UART RTDM driver");

struct rt_mxs_auart_port {

    unsigned long flags;
    unsigned int mctrl_prev;
    enum mxs_auart_type devtype;
    const struct vendor_data *vendor;

    struct clk *clk;
    struct clk *clk_ahb;


    unsigned char __iomem *membase; /* read/write[bwl] */
    resource_size_t     mapbase;        /* for ioremap */
    unsigned int irq;       /* irq number */
    int fifosize;            /* TX fifo size*/
    unsigned int uartclk;       /* base uart clock */
    struct rtdm_device rtdm_dev;    /* RTDM device structure */
};

static int mxs_get_clks(struct rt_mxs_auart_port *s, struct platform_device *pdev)
{
    int err;

    if (!is_asm9260_auart(s)) {
        s->clk = devm_clk_get(&pdev->dev, NULL);
        return PTR_ERR_OR_ZERO(s->clk);
    }

    s->clk = devm_clk_get(&pdev->dev, "mod");
    if (IS_ERR(s->clk)) {
        pr_err("Failed to get \"mod\" clk\n");
        return PTR_ERR(s->clk);
    }

    s->clk_ahb = devm_clk_get(&pdev->dev, "ahb");
    if (IS_ERR(s->clk_ahb)) {
        pr_err("Failed to get \"ahb\" clk\n");
        return PTR_ERR(s->clk_ahb);
    }

    err = clk_prepare_enable(s->clk_ahb);
    if (err) {
        pr_err("Failed to enable ahb_clk!\n");
        return err;
    }

    /*
    err = clk_set_rate(s->clk, clk_get_rate(s->clk_ahb));
    if (err) {
        dev_err(s->dev, "Failed to set rate!\n");
        goto disable_clk_ahb;
    }
    */
    err = clk_prepare_enable(s->clk);
    if (err) {
        pr_err("Failed to enable clk!\n");
        goto disable_clk_ahb;
    }


    return 0;

disable_clk_ahb:
    clk_disable_unprepare(s->clk_ahb);
    return err;
}

static int rt_serial_mxs_probe_dt(struct rt_mxs_auart_port *s,
        struct platform_device *pdev)
{
    struct device_node *np = pdev->dev.of_node;
    int ret;

    if (!np)
        /* no device tree device */
        return 1;

    ret = of_alias_get_id(np, "serial");
    if (ret < 0) {
        dev_err(&pdev->dev, "failed to get alias id: %d\n", ret);
        return ret;
    }
    pdev->id = ret;

    //s->port.line = ret;


    return 0;
}

static int rt_mxs_auart_probe(struct platform_device *pdev)
{

    const struct of_device_id *of_id =
            of_match_device(mxs_auart_dt_ids, &pdev->dev);
    //u32 version;
    int ret;
    //int irq;
    struct resource *r;

    //we're adding this
    struct rtdm_device *dev;
    struct rt_mxs_auart_port *s;

    //allocate managed kernel memory
    s = devm_kzalloc(&pdev->dev, sizeof(*s), GFP_KERNEL);
    if (!s)
        return -ENOMEM;

    //s->port.dev = &pdev->dev;
    //s->dev = &pdev->dev;

    ret = rt_serial_mxs_probe_dt(s, pdev);
    if (ret > 0)
        pr_info("If ret>0\n");
        //s->port.line = pdev->id < 0 ? 0 : pdev->id;//what do we do here?
    else if (ret < 0){
        return ret;
        }

    if (of_id) {
        pdev->id_entry = of_id->data;
        //s->devdata = of_id->data;
        s->devtype = pdev->id_entry->driver_data;
    }

    r = platform_get_resource(pdev, IORESOURCE_MEM, 0);
    if (!r)
        return -ENXIO;

    //get irq line
    s->irq = platform_get_irq(pdev, 0);
    if (s->irq < 0)
        return -ENODEV;

    //base memory
    //s->membase = devm_ioremap_resource(&pdev->dev, r);
    s->membase = ioremap(r->start, resource_size(r));
    if (IS_ERR(s->membase))
        return PTR_ERR(s->membase);

    /*define the rtdm_device*/
    dev = &s->rtdm_dev;
    dev->driver = &ida_driver;
    dev->label = "xeno_sprinte_ida";
    dev->device_data = s;

    ret = mxs_get_clks(s, pdev); //activate clocks
    if (ret)
        return ret;
    s->uartclk = clk_get_rate(s->clk);

    s->fifosize = MXS_AUART_FIFO_SIZE;

    mxs_init_regs(s);

    ret = rtdm_dev_register(dev); //register driver in RTDM space
    if (ret)
        return ret;

    platform_set_drvdata(pdev, s); //add device-related data to device struct

    pr_info("Probe: Successful\n");
    pr_info("%s on AUART%d: physical address=0x%p membase=0x%p irq=%d uartclk=%d\n",
           dev->name, pdev->id, r, s->membase, s->irq, s->uartclk);
    return 0;


}

static int rt_mxs_auart_remove(struct platform_device *pdev)
{
    struct rt_mxs_auart_port *s = platform_get_drvdata(pdev);
    struct rtdm_device *dev = &s->rtdm_dev;

    platform_set_drvdata(pdev, NULL);

    clk_disable_unprepare(s->clk);
    clk_disable_unprepare(s->clk_ahb);
    rtdm_dev_unregister(dev);

    pr_info("Remove: Successful\n");
    return 0;
}


static struct platform_driver rt_mxs_auart_driver = {
    .probe = rt_mxs_auart_probe,
    .remove = rt_mxs_auart_remove,
    .driver = {
        .name = "xeno_sprinte_ida",
        .of_match_table = mxs_auart_dt_ids,
    },
};


static int __init rt_mxs_auart_init(void)
{
    int ret;

    /*what library to include?
    if (!rtdm_available())
    return -ENODEV;
    */

    ret = platform_driver_register(&rt_mxs_auart_driver);
    if (ret) {
        pr_err("%s; Could not register  driver (err=%d)\n",
            __func__, ret);
    }

    pr_info("Init: Successful\n");
    return ret;
}

static void __exit rt_mxs_auart_exit(void)
{
    platform_driver_unregister(&rt_mxs_auart_driver);
    pr_info("Exit: Successful\n");
}

module_init(rt_mxs_auart_init);
module_exit(rt_mxs_auart_exit);
```

Does anyone have an idea?
Thanks!

Comment: `Does anyone have an idea?` Any idea about? (This is a Q&A site). If you have a problem with some driver, consult someone that wrote it. Or pay someone to fix it. Or fix it yourself. The driver is under GPL. Can't you shell the whole driver sources? `ipipe-SPOS` - what platform is that?

Comment: This is a driver that I'm building myself. My question was why does my system freeze when I'm unloading my driver and for that I have provided the log file as you have seen

Comment: Most probably the error is somewhere else in the code and your code invokes undefined behavior by writing out-of-bounds to any of the variables. Without an [MCVE], there is little help you can get. Please post an MCVE..  For starters, inspect kernel source code (elixir.bootlin like sites are your friends) and see why the `__warn` function kicks in, you have the whole stacktrace available. What platform are you programming on?

Comment: Thank you for your answer. If I may ask, why do you think that the error is somewhere else in the code? The line `clk_enable_lock` makes me believe that maybe this is related to the clocks I’m enabling in my code?

Comment: `why do you think that the error` Because C is a language with no protection against invalid code, once undefined behavior happens in code, the invalid behavior of the code can be anything and the wrong behavior can (and in 99% of most cases does) manifest itself in another part of the code.

Comment: Here's how I would proceed: Note what version of the kernel you're running. Obtain the exact kernel version's source code, then go look at the lines specified in the error message (e.g. `drivers/clk/clk.c:594`). This will point you toward the answer. My guess is that you have a ref-counting issue in your driver -- enables and disables must generally match one for one -- something like that. (In some cases, it appears that you're two warnings deep so probably want to first look at the one nearest the top of the stack as that will likely indicate the root cause.)

Comment: At least on the first glance you have issues (resource leaking, undone operations) with error path in `->probe()` and unneeded and potentially problematic NULL pointer assignment in `->remove()`. Try to clean up these first and check if it still an issue.

Comment: Thank you all for your inputs. @0andriy , can I ask what resource leaks you are referring to?